# WHM: how to add curl extension to PHP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, curl

i need **curl** installed on php. how can i add it using **WHM**?
and does it have any security issue or may couse problem for accounts on the shared host?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the command line (ssh or physical) run the follow command `/scripts/easyapache` which will allow you to recompile the apache with curl support any other available feature you may want.

EasyApache is a pre configured script that allows you to easily update Apache Web server through WHM or SSH.

> and does it have any security issue or
>   may couse problem for accounts on the
>   shared host?

It does not cause any trouble, as for the security it depends on how the users use it, depending it could be used to brute-force attack websites which would be a really bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can also configure it from the GUI in WHM under Software and EasyApache.